# Manually updating one line of code in an NPM module does not get carried over to app.js when running npm run dev

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3

Now I know that it's really not good practice to manually adjust anything in an NPM module :) But in this case there's a tiny error on one line in one module that is not being regularly updated. So rather than cloning the Github repo and basically creating my own custom module I really just want to correct that one line.

So I did that, but when I then run npm run dev or npm run prod it's not copying over the changed code. I tried npm install, even npm update, but it's never reflecting the updated code in app.js. Any ideas what I need to do to get it to pull in the updated code?

Comment: It's likely that the file you're changing isn't actually being loaded. Packages often include original source code in addition to the compiled/bundled script, and the bundled script is usually the one actively loaded. You can determine this from `package.json`'s `main` or `module` option. Perhaps you're editing the original source instead of the bundled script.

Comment: @tony19 thanks for your help. The package.json looks like this:

  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "dist/vue-quill.esm-bundler.js",

Index.js points to these files

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./dist/vue-quill.cjs.prod.js')
} else {
  module.exports = require('./dist/vue-quill.cjs.js')
}

And I've updated both the dist/vue-quill.esm-bundler.js and also the dist/vue-quill.cjs.js and dist/vue-quill.cjs.prod.js files. All of them have the correct code, yet after running npm run dev or npm run prod app.js still does not.

And ideas?

Comment: How are you importing this package? How are you checking for the change in `app.js`? Have you tried editing `index.js` instead? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: That's a good idea with editing the index.js @tony19 — I did that and it's working. Thanks for your help!